# how to write this kind of sql logic

Tags: php

I have 6 input that has the same name

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
   <input type="text" name="features[] value="Feature 1">
   <input type="hidden" name="feature_id[]" value="1">
</div>
```

.........

Some of the inputs might have values some of then might be empty.

I want to UPDATE values but in case the input is empty I want to INSERT it

I know this could be made easier then I tried to do this. In my below example
I iterate over array values that came from $_POST, trying update value but if the row count is 0 I'm executing insert query. The problem is when I'm inserting new values non-empty input values are being inserted too. 
All $_POST data is being saved in `$featuresData` array

Here is my code

ProperyData.php

```
 public function propertyData() {
     $featuresData = [
         "Features"  => $_POST['features'],
         "FeatureId" => $_POST['feature_id']
     ];
   return $data;
)
```

file.php

```
   $data = new PropertyData();

$featuresArr = $data->propertyData()['featuresData'];

for($i = 0; $i < count($featuresArr['Features']); $i++) {

   $update_features = "UPDATE features SET Feature_Title= :Feature WHERE idFeature = :id";

 $this->db->query($update_features);
 $this->db->bind(':Feature', $featuresArr['Features'][$i]);
 $this->db->bind(":id", $featuresArr['FeatureId'][$i]);
 $this->db->execute();

 if($this->db->rowCount() == 0) {
   $insert_features = "INSERT INTO features (Feature_Title, Appartment_ID) VALUES (:Feature, :id)";

 $this->db->query($insert_features);

 if(!empty($featuresArr['Features'][$i])) {

        $this->db->bind(':Feature', $featuresArr['Features'][$i]);
        $this->db->bind(":id", $id);
        $this->db->execute();
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you stores form data in `$featuresData` array and trying to loop on `$featuresArr`. You should loop on it.

```
$featuresData = [
     "Features"  => $_POST['features'],
     "FeatureId" => $_POST['feature_id']
 ];
```

Change to:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($featuresData['Features']); $i++) {

}
```

and fields as:

```
  $featuresData['Features'][$i]
    $featuresData['FeatureId'][$i]
```

See the input field name as you given.

```
<input type="text" name="features[]" value="Feature 2">
<input type="hidden" name="feature_id[]" value="2">
```

**Note:** you stores form data in `$featuresData` array. You should loop on it.

For non-empty values, you should put a condition before inserting data in loop as:

```
    if(empty($featuresData['Features'][$i]) && empty($featuresData['FeatureId'][$i])){
    // insert data query
    }else{
     // update data query
   }
```

Comment: sorry i should specify that i'm saving $_POST value inside another array. Updated post

Comment: He stored form data in `featuresData`;

Comment: see My updated answer. I think you put a condition to check input fields emptyness.

Comment: your condition will insert empty values, only thing that is not working in my query is when i'm inserting value it insert all non empty values, if for example i filled only 1 input

Comment: Yes exactly it will insert and what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I see two solutions.

First, you can SELECT... if it is there, update, if not, insert.

Second, possibly you can reverse your thinking and try INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE... But this will work only, if at lease one of values (possibly Appartment_ID ?) is UNIQUE (possibly primary key)

```
INSERT INTO features (Feature_Title, Appartment_ID) VALUES (:Feature, :id) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Feature_Title=values(Feature_Title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` feature, doing:

```
$update_features = "INSERT INTO `features` (`idFeature`, `Feature_Title`) VALUES (:id, :Feature) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `Feature_Title` = :Feature";

$this->db->query ( $update_features);
$this->db->bind ( ":Feature", $featuresData['Features'][$i]);
$this->db->bind ( ":id", $featuresData['FeatureId'][$i]);
$this->db->execute ();
```

If you need more informations, there's a MySQL [ON DUPLICATE](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/) tutorial.

Comment: sorry i should specify that i'm saving $_POST value inside another array. Updated post

Comment: `idFeature` is auto increment value and i need UPDATE Feature_Title only `WHERE Appartment_ID` matches value from `$id` variable